# Icons in TabLayout

Tags: android, android-tabs, android-design-library

I have a simple `AppCompatActivity` with one simple `Toolbar` (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar), one Design-Library `TabLayout` and one `ViewPager`.

Now I have in this case 4 fragments which are inside the viewpager and can be swiped from the sides. That works fine.
But as soon as I use `mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);`, the icons disappear but I can tab on the empty spaces which works fine. If I remove the line, the icons are visible again, the "swipe" works but if I tab to an icon, nothing happens.

**My Code**

*MainActivity*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private TabLayout mTabLayout;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private ViewPagerAdapter mAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initToolbar();
        initTabLayout();
        initViewPager();

        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);//Here is the code from above
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabLayout));

    }

    private void initToolbar() {
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

    }

    private void initTabLayout() {
        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_fire_white));
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_apps_white));
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_account_plus_white));
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_help_white));

    }

    private void initViewPager() {
        mAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), MainActivity.this);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

    //MENUE STUFF

}

//ViewPagerAdapter
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public static final int TABS_COUNT = 4;
    private Context context;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: return new HomeFragment1();
            case 1: return new HomeFragment2();
            case 2: return new HomeFragment3();
            case 3: return new HomeFragment4();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TABS_COUNT;
    }

}
```

*activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setupWithViewPager()` instantiate `Tab` that only have the title provided from the `ViewPager.Adapter`. Of course you can override this method to something like this:

```
public class IconicTabLayout extends TabLayout {

    private TabViewProvider mTabViewProvider;

    public interface TabViewProvider {
        Tab newTabInstance(int tabPosition);
    }

    public IconicTabLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public IconicTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public IconicTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void setTabProvider(TabViewProvider provider){
        mTabViewProvider = provider;
    }

    @Override
    public void setupWithViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        PagerAdapter adapter = viewPager.getAdapter();
        if (adapter == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ViewPager does not have a PagerAdapter set");
        } else {
            this.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(adapter);
            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(this));
            this.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void setTabsFromPagerAdapter(PagerAdapter adapter) {
        removeAllTabs();
        mTabViewProvider = mTabViewProvider == null && adapter instanceof TabViewProvider? (TabViewProvider)adapter : null;
  if(mTabViewProvider == null){   
        super.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(adapter);
    }else{
        for (int i = 0, count = adapter.getCount(); i < count; ++i) {
            this.addTab(mTabViewProvider.newTabInstance(i));
        }

    }
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
 mIconicTabLayout.setTabProvider(new TabViewProvider() {
        @Override
        public Tab newTabInstance(int tabPosition) {
            return mIconicTabLayout.newTab().setIcon(icons[position]);
        }
    });
    mIconicTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

Or

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements TabViewProvider{

   public void setTabLayout(TabLayout t){
      mTabLayout = t;
   }
  //...

    @Override
    public Tab newTabInstance(int position) {
                return mTabLayout.newTab().setIcon(icons[position]);
            }

}
```

Note:
Make sure you first call `setTabProvider` method or your `PagerAdapter` implement `TabViewProvider`, otherwise it will call default implementation.

Comment: Using the first method, it doesn't show icons on the tabs for me. I've tried both PNG files and XML (using selectors). Both didn't work. Using the second method, the icons can blink from time to time, especially when I use exitFadeDuration in the selectors or if I swipe fast. How come?

Answer (score 1):

You should initiate and add the icons inside the PagerAdapter.

```
private int[] imageResId = {
    R.drawable.ic_one,
    R.drawable.ic_two,
    R.drawable.ic_three
};

// ...

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
   // Generate title based on item position
 // return tabTitles[position];
Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResId[position]);
image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(), image.getIntrinsicHeight());
SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(" ");
ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
sb.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
return sb;
}
```

[Source](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout)

Comment: While i wouldn't necessarily call this the right answer i give it a mental +1 for ingenuity. A better way would be the setIcon() on the tab though.

Comment: I don't know. Have some sample code you could show? @androiddeveloper

Comment: Can't see that Chris Banes add both text and icons. ;)

Comment: @androiddeveloper I had the same problem like you and the drawables did not appear in the title. There's just one missing piece in the answer of _lagos_ and the problem is, that the style of the tab label has the property _textAllCaps_ set to _true_ which will prevent the ImageSpan from being rendered! So you just need a custom style for your TabLayout where textAllCaps is set to false. You can find more information and the needed styles here: [link](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout)

Comment: This showed the icons but they lost their selector capability (they did not change color on click)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to not call `setupWithViewPager()`. Instead you can hold `List` of the `Tabs`, and use the `PagerListener` to select the right `Tab`.

Something like this:

```
private List<TabLayout.Tab> tabList;

private void initTabLayout() {
    tabList = new ArrayList<>();
    tabList.add(mTabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_fire_white));
    tabList.add(mTabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_apps_white));
    tabList.add(mTabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_account_plus_white));
    tabList.add(mTabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_help_white));
    for (TabLayout.Tab tab : tabList){
        mTabLayout.addTab(tab);
    }
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            tabList.get(position).select();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

}
```